# How to run an R script that lives in a jar file

Tags: java, r, executable-jar

I have Java application that is deployed as a jar and run from a cmd line by calling a main function.  There are some tools that are written in R associated with the application that are distributed with the application.

I'd like to enable calling the R scripts that are in the jar file from either the cmd line or from Java.

How can I execute an R script from either the cmd line or Java when the R script is in a jar file (with out unzipping the jar file).

Answer (score 0):

You can access the R script by getting an `InputStream` for it and reading the file content:

```java
try (InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("script.R")) {
    //read from inputStream
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'd recommend reading more into the packing of JARs and how to include/store resources.

With the contents of the R script, you can execute it using approaches such as the one mentioned in [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-r-integration) (using libraries to execute R).